# Thread safe unique_ptr move

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Is it possible to safely move unique_ptr with c++11 atomic operations?

Currently I have a code like this

```
std::unique_ptr<SyncToken> DataManager::borrowSyncToken()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> syncTokenLock(syncTokenMutex);
    return std::move(syncToken);
}
```

I am wondering whether there is some more elegant way, like simply declaring:

```
std::atomic<std::unique_ptr<SyncToken>> syncToken;
```

and avoiding the need of mutex. Or possibly I don't need to care about the lock here at all and std::move is already atomic?

After research I made so far it seems to me:

- the std::move itself is not atomic and needs to have some synchronization around otherwise 2 threads calling my method concurrently may end up with 2 copies of some undefined pointers.
- the std::atomic declaration compiles for me, but I don't know how to initialize it and and make the move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The value `T` which you pass to `std::atomic` needs to be trivially copyable, which `std::unique_ptr`is not. Operations like `std::atomic::load` or `std::atomic::store` take T objects by value.

Packing something in a `std::atomic` also doesn't make operations from the value atomic.

When using `std::unique_ptr` in an atomic context, you have to think about the fact that you might have problems when it comes to managing resources. You never know how many threads still refer to your data, this problem can be solved with a `std::shared_ptr` which uses atomic reference counting. (You need to check whether it's really atomic by using the `std::atomic_is_lock_free` function. )

One thing I was also stumbling upon when looking in your code is the intent of the `borrowSyncToken` function. It's called borrow but you pass ownership of the token to the caller by moving out the `std::unique_ptr`, how is the ownership passed back and what do other threads get when the DataManager currently doesn't own the token?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and discussion of the std::shared_ptr. For the intent: the code is simplified, but I think even so it would return nullptr to later threads allowing a caller to find out that the token is not available. Problem solved here I will explain in other comment.

Comment: Clients do two types of operations on DataManager: reading, writing. Only one client can write in the time. **Clients are not threads** - sometimes yes, sometimes there may be a background job launched for the client. reading/writing does not mean a simple operation but following a complex communication protocol between DataManager and client. The client requests are not necessarily to be blocked until token available but sometimes actively refused. To orient in the mess I proposed this SyncToken - writer needs to borrow SyncToken and call returnSyncToken(unique_ptr<SyncToken>) when finished.